# PHP + PDO/MySQL: how to automatically query to find out VARCHAR field lengths?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

is there a way to use PHP+PDO to query a MySQL database and find out the column widths of some VARCHAR fields? I don't want to hardcode them into my PHP file if possible.

(purpose: determine maximum lengths of strings to be either inserted into these columns, or compared against existing data in the columns.)

Comment: Do you want the table definition, the actual size/length of a column of a specific row or the maximum length in a given result set?

Comment: thx, I'll qualify above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read it from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html)

Answer (score 5):

Just shoot a query to the `information_schema`.`columns` table and filter out the row you need. The value you're looking for is stored under 'CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH'.

Answer (score 2):

Select CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME='yourcolumn' and TABLE_NAME='yourtable';

Answer (score 1):

Run this query: 'DESCRIBE `table_name`' where table_name is the name of the table you're looking for information about. It'll return what you're looking for.

Comment: possible, but involves too much parsing compared to the information_schema approach.